# Issue on installing yii2-braintree via composer

Tags: composer-php, braintree

I've installed the Braintree component via composer successfully, and now I wish to install, also using composer, the [yii2-braintree](https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-braintree).

I inserted, just like it's recommended, the `"bryglen/yii2-braintree": "*"` line in the `require` section of my **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "2.37.0",
    "bryglen/yii2-braintree": "*"
},
```

After that, I executed `composer update` and the result was:

```
sudo composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                                                                                                                            Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package bryglen/yii2-braintree could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the repo?

Comment: Installed it right now without any problems. Do you have this setting in your `composer.json`: `"minimum-stability": "dev"`? Seems like it's missing. This extension doesn't have stable releases yet.

Comment: @arogachev Yes, you are right. But now another error appeared. What's your installed **braintree_php** version? I installed the last ([2.37.0](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/setup)) and for installing yii2-braintree, it seems to require 2.30.0. "No matching package found" is what it shows.

Comment: I installed just `yii2-braintree`, `braintree_php` was installed as dependency. Yes, version is static - `2.30.0`.

Comment: Thanks, @arogachev. If you wish, you can answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have this setting in your `composer.json`:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Seems like it's missing. This extension doesn't have stable releases yet.

Install just `yii2-braintree`, `braintree_php` will be installed as dependency with static version - **2.30.0**.